# Mathf.SmoothDamp happens instantly (Unity 3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have 2 functions for zooming the gun out and one for zooming the gun out.

The zoom out gets called in Update() when the player speed reaches a certain number as well as the zoom in.

Here are the functions:

```
    void MakeGunFurther()
    {
        float refVel = 0;
        float normalFOV = gunCam.fieldOfView; 
        gunCam.fieldOfView = Mathf.SmoothDamp(normalFOV, 55f, ref refTest, 0.1f);
        
    }
    void MakeGunCloser()
    {
        
        float refVel = 0;
        gunCam.fieldOfView = Mathf.SmoothDamp(47, 55, ref refTest, 0.1f);
        hasRan = false;

    }
```

#### Now, my problem is that the first function works fine and makes the gun smoothly zoom out, BUT when i need to zoom it in again with the second function it just instantly does it not smoothly like the first one.

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Does **MakeGunFurther** end up making the target ~ 55f? if so, then why would we start from 47 in **MakeGunCloser**. Something seems odd about the first 2 parameters in **gunCam.fieldOfView** of **MakeGunCloser** https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothDamp.html

Comment: Was also wondering about this. Also would recommend declaring normalFOV out of that void or at least use it in both MakeGunCloser and MakeGunFarther. Possibly could be misunderstanding normalFOV for something possibly like currentFOV.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari yes i just switched them around because for some reason when they were in  the right order it didnt change anything at a;ll so thats why the target and current are switched.

Comment: @Karim.k currently are they coded as `gunCam.fieldOfView = Mathf.SmoothDamp(55, 47, ref refTest, 0.1f);` or `gunCam.fieldOfView = Mathf.SmoothDamp(55f, 47f, ref refTest, 0.1f);` Could possibly be a datatype issue.

Comment: @OstenGibson I tried adding the ' f ' but sadly still the same thing :(

Comment: This is what calls the functions (from Update()) if it helps: 

`if (player_speed <35 && hasRan)
        {
            MakeGunCloser();
            
        }
 if(player_speed >= 40)
        {
            hasRan = true;
           
            MakeGunFurther();
            
        }`

Comment: @Karim.k and the definition for `ref refTest` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't had the chance to use [Mathf.SmoothDamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothDamp.html) in Unity but I see where the issue likely happens.

First, you might want to consider scoping your upper and lower points of field of view at the class level of the mono script. Perhaps even Serialize it so you can play around with it in play mode.

```
public float normalFieldOfView = 55f;
public float zoomedInFieldOfView = 47f; //If I got that correct from the script
```

You would also need to keep track of velocity for **Mathf.SmoothDamp** in the ref parameter outside the method. This would probably be reset to some value (maybe 0f) every time you complete zooming in and out (not enough info to give you a suggestion).

```
private float currentZoomVelocity = 0f;
```

Second, might want to re-write your functions as such.

```
void MakeGunFurther()
{
    gunCam.fieldOfView = Mathf.SmoothDamp(gunCam.fieldOfView, normalFieldOfView, ref currentZoomVelocity, 0.1f);    
}

void MakeGunCloser()
{
    gunCam.fieldOfView = Mathf.SmoothDamp(gunCam.fieldOfView, zoomedInFieldOfView, ref currentZoomVelocity, 0.1f);
    hasRan = false;
}
```

But again, you have to ensure that you correctly reset the currentZoomVelocity every time zoom in and zoom out is completed.

Comment: I I did everything you said but i dont quite know where or how to reset the currentZoomVelocity. Could you please tell me where exactly should i reset it ? thank you

Comment: if you need any extra info tell me

Comment: UPDATE: i figured how to reset it so its always 0 but still after that it still doesnt zoom out smoothly. Weird bug :0

Comment: Can you clarify what *doesnt zoom out smoothly* means?

Comment: Hello everyone i found the answer to this problem here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1781962/mathfsmoothdamp-happends-instantly.html

(i asked the question here and on this link)

Hope this helps anyone in the future!

(also im banned from posting answers so thats why im posting in the comments)

Comment: Technically it's the same as this answer other than the fact that he mentioned to increase the time 0.1f. It wasn't clear what doesn't zoom out smoothly meant but I had a feeling it might be in that direction. Anyhow, glad you got the answer you needed.